# How to send data with the size more than Signalr message size limit in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, webassembly

We know that `Blazor` uses `SignalR` for communication between client and server and also there is a message size limitation in `SignalR`(which is currently **32k**). How it is possible to send more than 32k data from server to client or vise versa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-38654&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options),

You can set `MaximumReceiveMessageSize`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
    {
        hubOptions.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this configuration really affects the Blazor SignalR Hub? Or just affects the configuration of another SignalR HUB that you will add in the pipeline?

Comment: In my experience this code (I think this is the old way of doing it) did make a difference for large file uploads:

services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(o =>
{
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
});

See: https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader

Comment: @MichaelWashington The MS link you reference for large data transfers doesn't seem to point to the correct place.

Comment: @Mmm - Yeah Microsoft removed the page. I removed the link