# Blazor ProtectedSessionStorage timeout

Tags: asp.net, blazor, session-storage

Hey I´m currently working on a blazor-server-app and encountered a problem.

I´m using the protected session storage to save my data.
If the value of a key exceeds a certain amount of characters (34160) the circuit starts attempt to reconnect and recovers. However the application is in a frozen state.

I try to access the storage inside the OnInitializedAsync method.

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    Warenkorb = await SessionStorageService.GetNotNull<Warenkorb>( SessionStorageKeys.WarenkorbKey );
 }
```

Inside the SessionStorageService:

```
 public async Task<T> GetNotNull<T>( string key )
 {
    ProtectedBrowserStorageResult<string> result = await protectedSessionStorage.GetAsync<string>( key );
 }
```

Debugger stops at "GetAsync(key)"

Is there any explanation for this?
Thanks

Comment: I found a solution increasing the MaximumReceiveMessageSize as in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713951/how-to-send-data-with-the-size-more-than-signalr-message-size-limit-in-blazor

Comment: Thank you! This would also explain why my Application froze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find an explanation, but since I faced same problem I ended up with next workaround:

Create a Session class with a Guid Id and any other properties you might need as session state:

```
public class Session
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
```

Create an application state class to maintain a collection of Sessions:

```
public class AppState
{
    public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; } = new();

    public Session AddSession() {
        var retval = new Session();
        Sessions.Add(retval);
        return retval;
    }

    public Session? Session(Guid? sessionId) => Sessions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Guid == sessionId);
}
```

Register it on Program.cs as a Singleton service:

```
var state = new TestState.Shared.AppState(http);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => state);
```

Create a SessionProvider component which will create a new session n AppState if missing and persist it's Id on the Protected Session Storage:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore
@inject AppState AppState

@if (isLoaded)
{
    <CascadingValue Value="@this">
        @ChildContent
    </CascadingValue>
}
else
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    public Session? Session { get; set; }
    public bool isLoaded;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<Guid>("sessionId");
            if (result.Success)
                Session = AppState.Session(result.Value);
            else
            {
                Session = AppState.AddSession();
                await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("sessionId", Session.Guid);
            }
            isLoaded = true;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Wrap App.razor Router component with SessionProvider:

```
<SessionProvider>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</SessionProvider>
```

Access Session properties from any page:

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<div>session id: @sessionProvider?.Session?.Id.ToString()</div>

<p role="status">Current count: @sessionProvider?.Session?.Counter</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public SessionProvider? sessionProvider { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        if (sessionProvider?.Session != null)
            sessionProvider.Session.Counter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes this is a good and legit solution. I find it usefull to use a scoped service instead of the Singleton tho.