# Blazor: InputFile; When file over 1 MB in size, OnChange won't trigger

Tags: blazor

I am running into an issue.
I have this file uploader:

```
<InputFile OnChange="@SingleUpload" class="custom-input-file" />
```

Connected to the SingleUpload Method:

```
private async Task SingleUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var UploadedStream = new MemoryStream();
    await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(UploadedStream);
    UploadedByteArray = UploadedStream.ToArray();
}
```

It works fine and triggers with small files. But everything over 1 MB doesn't even trigger.

I already set the buffer of the websocket to be 10 MB:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(o =>
{
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10mb max file size
});
```

Still to no avail.
What's the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send data with the size more than Signalr message size limit in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713951/how-to-send-data-with-the-size-more-than-signalr-message-size-limit-in-blazor)

Comment: https://forum.radzen.com/t/upload-large-file-is-null/11471

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, Blazor WASM or Blazor Server Side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Asp.Net Core 5.0 and above, **OpenReadStream** enforces a maximum size in bytes of its Stream. Reading one file or multiple files larger than *500 KB* results in an exception. This limit prevents developers from accidentally reading large files into memory. The *maxAllowedSize* parameter of OpenReadStream can be used to specify a larger size if required. [Check Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
var stream = e.File.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024);
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
```

Comment: damn son, you solved all my issues! <3